# Do Gorenstein rings necessarily have a finite projective dimension (as a module over itself)?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Do Gorenstein rings necessarily have finite projective dimensions?

Comment: What? Every ring $R$ has finite projective dimension as an
$R$-module. Is that what you want to ask? If not, then what
exactly?

Comment: @robin projective dim of a ring $R$ is (sometimes) defined to be the supremum of the projective dim of $R$-modules.

Comment: Of course. Sorry, I was being dumb (it happens quite often).

Comment: Manish, I believe that is commonly called global dimension of $R$. No, I didn't mean that. I meant what Robin suggested.

Comment: oops, seems like I have forgotten some commutative algebra term.

Comment: It is better to also edit the actual text of the question, not only the title. In any case, you surely did not want to ask «Do Gorenstein rings necessarily have a finite projective dimension (as a module over itself)?» because then the answer is trivially yes: *every* ring is projective over itself!

Comment: Mariano, yes, I was debating over whether I should delete the trivial question, but that means deleting all the comments and answers along with it.

Comment: I have voted to close, this question is trivial as stated. 

Comment: Voting to close for the same reason as Hailong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ for a field $k$. This is a self-injective $k$-algebra (that is, it is an injective module over itself), so it is Gorenstein. Yet the residue field is of infinite projective dimension.

Comment: Thanks. How do I see that the residue field of A has infinite projective dimension?

Comment: @kwan: compute a projective resolution: it will be clear quite fast that the dimension is infinite.

Comment: I see. I get an infinite minimal free resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No. There is a result of Serre/Auslander-Buchsbaum which says a noethrian local ring is regular if and only if the residue field has finite free resolution. So just take any Gorenstein singularity as an example.

Comment: What is Gorenstein singularity?

Comment: A local Gorenstein ring that's not regular.